# Replace duplicate results with blank

Tags: sql-server

I am looking to omit duplicate lines of data from my results list.

```
declare @Table1 TABLE(
    ID int not null,
    OrderNo varchar(5) not null)

declare @Table2 TABLE(
    OrderID int not null,
    Invoice varchar(7) not null)

declare @Table3 TABLE(
    OrderID int not null,
    Payment varchar(7) not null)

insert into @Table1 values (1,'14598'),(2,'14599'),(3,'14600'),(4,'14601')
insert into @Table2 values (1,'35.01'),(1,'396.90'),(1,'79.00'),(2,'786.20'),(3,'40.00'),(3,'93.60'),(3,'43.60'),(4,'15.08')
insert into @Table3 values (1,'20.50'),(1,'180.00'),(2,'786.20'),(2,'15.20'),(2,'186.20'),(3,'40.00'),(3,'93.60'),(3,'43.60'),(4,'15.08')

select t1.ID, t2.Invoice, t3.Payment from @Table1 t1
join @Table2 t2 on t2.OrderID = t1.ID
join @Table3 t3 on t3.OrderID = t1.ID
```

Table data:

```
Table1
ID |  OrderNo
-------------
1  |  14598
2  |  14599
3  |  14600
4  |  14601

Table2
OrderID |  Invoice
------------------
1       |   35.01
1       |  396.90
1       |   79.00
2       |  786.20
3       |   40.00
3       |   93.60
3       |   43.60
4       |   15.08

Table3
OrderID | Payment
-----------------
1       |   20.50
1       |  180.00
2       |  786.20
2       |   15.20
2       |  186.20
3       |   40.00
3       |   93.60
3       |   43.60
4       |   15.08
```

When I try joining all three of these tables together, I get the following:

```
ID | Invoice | Payment
----------------------
1  | 35.01   | 20.50
1  | 35.01   |180.00
1  | 396.90  | 20.50
1  | 396.90  |180.00
1  | 79.00   | 20.50
1  | 79.00   |180.00
2  | 786.20  |786.20
2  | 786.20  | 15.20
2  | 786.20  |186.20
3  | 40.00   | 40.00
3  | 40.00   | 93.60
3  | 40.00   | 43.60
3  | 93.60   | 40.00
3  | 93.60   | 93.60
3  | 93.60   | 43.60
3  | 43.60   | 40.00
3  | 43.60   | 93.60
3  | 43.60   | 43.60
4  | 15.08   | 15.08
```

Now as you can see, order 2 only has a single invoice in Table2, however has 3 payments in Table3.  I do want to display 3 lines, with each of the Payments on a separate line, however I don't want it to repeat the single Invoice on each subsequent line.

Subsequently with order 1, there are 3 invoices in Table2, however only 2 payments in Table3.  Currently it is showing everything from Table3 for each entry in Table2, resulting in 6 lines instead of 3.

I only want to report on each amount once, with subsequent lines (if generated due to more than the number of results being in another table) showing blanks.  Selecting DISTINCT doesn't accomplish this.  Is there any way of achieving what I am after here?

```
ID | Invoice | Payment
----------------------
1  | 35.01   | 20.50
1  | 396.90  | 180.00
1  | 79.00   |
2  | 786.20  | 786.20
2  |         | 15.20
2  |         | 186.20
```

Comment: why don't you do this in your front end application ?

Comment: The full dataset contains more than 1.8m rows of data currently, the resulting Excel file exceeds 150mb, doing any kind of formula on this dataset results in the computer being unusable for a significant amount of time while Excel uses all of the processor cores available.

Comment: you can use LAG(), LEAD() window function to do it

Comment: do you still need help?

Comment: Jaydip and santoshkumar have replied with their own iterations, however neither satisfy the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        declare @Table1 TABLE(
            ID int not null,
            OrderNo varchar(5) not null)

        declare @Table2 TABLE(
            OrderID int not null,
            Invoice varchar(7) not null)

        declare @Table3 TABLE(
            OrderID int not null,
            Payment varchar(7) not null)

        insert into @Table1 values (1,'14598'),(2,'14599'),(3,'14600'),(4,'14601')
        insert into @Table2 values (1,'35.01'),(1,'396.90'),(1,'79.00'),(2,'786.20'),(3,'40.00'),(3,'93.60'),(3,'43.60'),(4,'15.08')
        insert into @Table3 values (1,'20.50'),(1,'180.00'),(2,'786.20'),(2,'15.20'),(2,'186.20'),(3,'40.00'),(3,'93.60'),(3,'43.60'),(4,'15.08')

        select isnull(t2.OrderID,t3.OrderID) AS ID,t2.Invoice,
        t3.Payment 
        from
         @Table1 t1
        join (select *,Row_number()over(partition by OrderID  order by (select 1))rn from @Table2) t2 on t2.OrderID = t1.ID
        full join
       (select *,Row_number()over(partition by OrderID  order by (select 1))rn2 from @Table3) t3 
              on t3.OrderID = t2.OrderID and t2.rn=t3.rn2 ;

    ----------------------
    ID  Invoice Payment
    -----------------------
    1   35.01   20.50
    1   396.90  180.00
    1   79.00   NULL
    2   786.20  786.20
    2   NULL    15.20
    2   NULL    186.20
    3   40.00   40.00
    3   93.60   93.60
    3   43.60   43.60
    4   15.08   15.08
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't satisfy the condition for the Payment in ID=1, it reports a duplicate Payments.

Comment: Perfect, this satisfies both conditions.  Thank you kindly good sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as well using derive table or CTE as below

```
WITH CTE AS(
     select t1.ID, 
            t2.Invoice, 
            t3.Payment,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID,t2.Invoice ORDER BY t1.ID ) RN
     from @Table1 t1
     join @Table2 t2 on t2.OrderID = t1.ID
     join @Table3 t3 on t3.OrderID = t1.ID
)
select ID, 
       CASE WHEN RN > 1 THEN NULL ELSE Invoice END, 
       Payment
FROM CTE
```

Comment: While this works for Invoice amounts, it doesn't for Payment amounts, it's still reporting all Payment amounts per Invoice amount, even if the Invoice line reports a NULL.